# iOS Simulator freezes, but only on one profile

Tags: macos, ios-simulator, osx-mavericks

I ran into this when I tried to deploy my app to the iOS simulator earlier today - the debugger never connected, and the iOS simulator crashed.  Now I can't get the simulator to do anything.

When I first launch the simulator I get a black screen (no tiles from the dashboard), and pressing the home button makes it freeze.  If I access the menus at the top of the screen in OSX, that works until I press the home button, then it freezes.

Things I've tried:

- Creating a new project in Xamarin Studio and running that
- Creating a new project in Xcode and running that
- Opening up the Xcode package contents and running the simulator .app from there
- Clearing the simulator's Content and Settings.
- Reinstalling Xcode fresh (5.0.2)
- Pressing the home button (or whatever it's called) on the simulator

I created a new profile on OSX and running the simulator from there, and it froze for a good 20 seconds, then all of a sudden I saw the tiles appear for the home page.  I then switched back to my original OSX profile, still didn't work.

The problem seems to be something with my profile, but I have no idea what to look at next.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

GOT IT!  The problem was a file located in /Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/

the iPhoneSimulator folder was missing - or it looked like it was a link to a missing folder.  I deleted it, ran the simulator, and it was fixed.